# New VM won't launch

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04

Setting up VirtualBox on new install of 22.04. I had it running but it wasn't right ("kernel signing problem"). So I disabled Secure Boot and reinstalled VB. Seemed to go fine, with no errors.

It wouldn't open the Win10 VM I had created so I deleted that and started over. Still won't open the VM. I get this error message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine win10-vb.

Failed to load R0 module /usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0: Unable to locate imported symbol 'SUPR0FpuBegin' for module 'VMMR0.r0' (VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND).

Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Is anyone able to interpret this for me and advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just running `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` on the host machine fixed the issue.

The error can occur if you end up with multiple copies of VirtualBox on the same machine. In this case, [this thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=106582&sid=b3d6428e09fd44d0c2f7bb5a14b89909&start=15#p523932) recommends removing the dkms version
`sudo apt remove virtualbox-dkms`

The error can also result in a corrupt module or a module that isn't compiled for your kernel. In these cases, try uninstalling all versions of VirtualBox then re-installing.